# Send photo/image to application

Tags: iphone, ios

Does anyone know if it's possible to get your application on this screen?
Or is this ability only able for Apple?

I did some searching but couldn't find anything relevant, I wasn't exactly sure what to even call this screen.

I'm new so I can't post images...but basically on an iPhone 5, open up a picture. Click the icon that has a rectangle with an arrow jumping out of it. The menu that pop's up is the one I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, for no good reason, Apple doesn't list any 3rd party apps in the Photos app even for apps that register the fact that they can open such files.

If you want this feature, file an enhancement request using [Apple's bug reporting tool](http://bugreporter.apple.com).

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, no there is no way to get your application on that list.

For some reason Apple handles images with their own activity sheet.

To get images off the camera roll, look into [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)